# geom_text(), plotmath, and %

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath, geom-text

I want to add "R^2 = 70%" to my plot using geom_text() (where ^ indicates a superscript).

Without the % sign, it's easy:

```
my.data <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5)
p1      <- ggplot(my.data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p1      <- p1 + geom_text(x=2.5, y=5, label="R^2 == 70", parse=TRUE)
p1
```

Adding % is trickier than expected.
I managed to get it by adding a second geom_text() statement:

```
p1 <- p1 + geom_text(x=2.63, y=4.97, label="%")
p1
```

How can it be done with a single geom_text() statement?

Answer (score 4):

This works...

```
geom_text(x=2.5, y=5, label="R^2 == 70*'%'", parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's the * that I was missing.

Comment: Yes, you have to fool plotmath into thinking it is multiplying 70 by a variable called '%'.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(ggplot2)

my.data <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5)
ggplot(my.data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  annotate("text", x = 2.5, y = 5, label = "paste(R ^ 2, \" = 70\", \"%\" )", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]